# Turning off some sProp checks

Tags: agda, inductive-type, prop

In [Definitional Proof Irrelevance Without K](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01859964/), inductives in sProp need to satisfy three conditions to allow large elimination:

> (1) Every non-forced argument must be in sProp. 
> (2) The return types of constructors must be pairwise orthogonal. 
> (3) Every recursive call must satisfy a syntactic guard condition

I have the following data definition in Agda (I have `T`, `<` defined elsewhere, but given as postulates here for a MWE):

```
{-# OPTIONS --prop #-}

postulate
  T : Set
  _<_ : T → T → Set

data Acc (x : T) : Prop where
  acc : (∀ y → y < x → Acc y) → Acc x
```

Now I'd like to throw caution to the wind and eliminate `Acc` to something in `Set` at the expense of, as I understand it, possible nonterminating type checking. Evidently right now that's not possible since `Acc` violates (3) (and this is explicitly stated as an example in the paper), yielding the type checking error:

```
Cannot split on datatype in Prop unless target is in Prop
when checking that the pattern acc p has type Acc x
```

Is there some way of only turning (3) off? Perhaps with something like `{- NON_TERMINATING -}`... somewhere? I'm confident I won't actually run into nontermination issues (I've previously proven the wellfoundedness of `<`, for one), and I'd like to type check the rest of my proofs without disregarding safety *entirely*.

EDIT: I'd be interested to know if it'd be possible to do the same in Coq as well, which currently gives me this error:

```
Fixpoints on proof irrelevant inductive types should produce proof irrelevant values.
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there is no way to turn it off. It is also worth pointing out that the cost is greater than you expected.

```
data A : Prop where
  a b : A
```

It is possible to prove `eq : (B : Set)(f : A → B) → f a ≡ f b` with `refl`. So if you were allowed to turn off the check, it does not leads to non-terminating type checking. Rather, it produces impossible cases and breaks subject reduction (i.e. if a term is well-typed, then after you perform evaluation of the term, it always remains well-typed).

In particular, in your case it immediately leads to a contradiction. You have a proof of False that is well-typed (of type `Empty`). But when you normalize it, the resulting term is no longer well-typed.

There are a few ways to solve this:

- Use `Set`. Why did you use `Prop` in the first place?
- Use `Prop` also for your target type. Why does it have to be in `Set`?
- Postulate an elimination function using the `postulate` keyword. You should probably not expect any sort of computation, because that always breaks subject reduction.

Comment: What's the proof of `Empty` that I'd get if `Acc` in sProp were allowed to be eliminated?

Comment: @ionchy Is it true that there are at most one element of each `p < q`? If so, simply prove that (or postulate that if you don't want to bother) and I think you wouldn't lose much using `Set`, you just have to insert `transport`s along the way. If it is *not* the case, then my argument immediately applies.

Comment: I am defining (well, postulating above) `p < q` in `Set`, it's `Acc p` rather that I'd like to put in sProp. The fact that any `Acc p` only has one proof is actually provable up to propositional equality if I postulate function extensionality, come to think of it.

Comment: @ionchy Yes I misread. It's true that `Acc` is propositionally singletons. But if there are elements that are not equal *on the nose* (for instance, one function does a useless case analysis on the parameter, and another does not), it still breaks subject reduction.

Comment: I don't remember of any way (except using bugs) to break subject reduction in Agda.

Comment: Having Acc in SProp (with its eliminator) shouldn't break consistency: you can embed that type theory in Extensional Type Theory (adding an equality reflection rule) which has models (at least in a metatheory that is strong enough, e.g., ZFC+enough inaccessible cardinals)

Answer (score 3):

In Coq, you can probably hack your way around by unsetting the guard condition and writing a fixpoint that is "semantically" guarded but not syntactically so. Something along the lines of what is below.

```
Inductive sAcc (A : Type) (R : A -> A -> Prop) (x : A) : SProp :=
| sAcc_intro : (forall y : A, R y x -> sAcc A R y) -> sAcc A R x.

#[bypass_check(guard)]
Definition sAcc_rect (A : Type) (R : A -> A -> Prop) (P : A -> Type)
  (f : forall x : A, (forall y : A, R y x -> sAcc A R y) -> (forall y : A, R y x -> P y) -> P x) :
  forall (x : A) (a : sAcc A R x), P x :=

  (fix F (u : unit) (x : A) (a : sAcc A R x) {struct u} : P x :=
    f x (match a with sAcc_intro _ _ _ a => a end)
      (fun y r => F tt y (match a with sAcc_intro _ _ _ k => k y r end))
  ) tt.
```

You have to be careful though, because this will explode as soon as you try to perform a weak head on this. So you'll have to work around unification and kernel type-checking by making some conversions explicit. Alternatively, you may try to guard the fixpoint by some dummy argument, e.g. by keeping the unit argument abstract.